# iterate all properties in the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have List (Of Report). Report has 90 properties. I dont want write them each and every propertiy to get values for properties. Is there any waht to get propeties values from the List

Ex:

```
Dim mReports as new List(Of Reports)
mReport = GetReports()

For each mReport as Report In mReports
   'Here I want get all properties values without writing property names
next
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
static readonly PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Reports).GetProperties();

foreach(var property in properties) {
    property.GetValue(someInstance);
}
```

However, it will be slow.

In general, a class with 90 proeprties is poor design.
Consider using a Dictionary or rethinking your design.

Answer (score 1):

```
PropertyInfo[] props = 
     obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
{
  Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak VB.NET fluently, but you can easily translate something like this to VB.NET.

```
var properties = typeof(Report).GetProperties();
foreach(var mReport in mReports) {
    foreach(var property in properties) {
       object value = property.GetValue(mReport, null);
       Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is called [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29). You can read about its uses in .NET on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx). I used [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx) to get the list of properties, and [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) to read the values. You might need to add various [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) or check properties like `PropertyInfo.CanRead` to get exactly the properties that you want. Additionally, if you have any indexed properties, you will have to adjust the second parameter to `GetValue` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good fit for reflection or meta-programming (depending on the performance required).

```
var props=typeof(Report).GetProperties();
foreach(var row in list)
foreach(var prop in props)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",
        prop.Name,
        prop.GetValue(row));
```